# Entity Framework not appearing in Add New Item list in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017

I created a new MVC project in Visual Studio 2017. I wanted to add an EDMX file (I will be doing database-first) so right clicked on the project and selected Add|New Item.

However, I cannot find the Entity Framework components that were available in the previous versions of Visual Studio. Does anyone know where they went?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In .NET Framework-based projects, the Entity Framework 6 templates are still there. However, for .NET Core-based projects, I believe you're expected to use the `dotnet ef` commands. This includes a means of scaffolding a code-first `DbContext` from an existing database. See [ASP.NET Core - Existing Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db).

To verify this, I setup a demo project with the following structure:

[image: solution-explorer]

The **New Item/Data** dialog for the **.NET Framework** project:

[image: framework-new-item]

Note that there is also an `EF POCO Generator` template available in the **Online** templates section that may be of interest to you:

[image: core-poco-generator]

Comment: So, are you suggesting I'm using .NET Core? Because that certainly wasn't my intention. I just created a standard MVC application.

Comment: Did you create a .NET Core based web application, or a .NET Framework based web application? You can certainly do both.

Comment: From my understanding about .NET Core, I don't want to use it at all. But I think you are right. I actually created another project in the solution--a class library--and was trying to add an EDMX to *that* project. These options are available to my main project. Now I just need to figure out how to add a class library project. (.NET Core, .NET Standard, .NET Framework, ugh! This was very simple before.)

Comment: I know it's a little confusing at first, but I actually really appreciate the fact both are there. Recently, I updated my web platform from MVC 5 / AngularJS to ASP.NET Core / Angular 2, and it's been an awesome change.

Comment: I'd be curious to hear how it's better. Isn't Core just a lighter version of the frameworks? For an app running on a web server, how is that good?

Comment: It's more than just making the framework more lightweight, it's also about making segments of the framework modular and developed independent of each other. There's also integrated Dependency Injection, a better middleware pipeline, and tighter integration with open source technologies, among other things. I'd definitely not just disregard it.

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar issue today after i updated my VS to the latest 2017 version. I tried to open an .edmx file in VS2017 and it didn't show the designer view. So i realised i forgot to select Entity Framework tools during the installation:

[image]

Everything is back to normal :)

Comment: Once you have this installed, how do you get the ADO.NET Entity Data Model option to display?  
More importantly, since there is no Data option under Visual C# items, just "Database", how do you get that to work?

Comment: @DaveN I think you only need to check the "Entity Framework 6 Tools" option.

Comment: That option is definitely checked, however, I found out there are no MS tools (code generators) for EF for DotNetCore applications, yet (at least not in the GUI) - Jaime Still's answered that question. No biggy.

Comment: I'm currently only working with standard MVC and haven't worked with ASP.NET Core yet :)

Comment: Core is currently a developmental and debugging nightmare, so I'm abandoning it until it's more mature (maybe version 2.0). There are so many places it breaks, I'll just wait til everyone else debugs Microsoft's latest mess. Fiddled for a couple of weeks, and, decided, this new project will not be going that direction.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. In that case i'll wait a little longer to check it out :)

Comment: This solution worked for me. Just in case if someone is not aware - you can launch the Visual Studio Installer to modify installation at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer" path (File name: vs_installer.exe)

Comment: This is true answer. install EF6 tools in modifying Visual Studio. Solved problem.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is late, but I ran into the same exact issue. After reading some of the other answers, I realized I had created a .Net project with Standard library instead of the Framework library.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issues, But in my Visual Studio 2017, I am not able to see Framework library. kindly guide me, how can open class library as .Net Framework library.

Comment: @Pratham4950 In the Add New Project window, try looking under Installed => Visual C# => Windows Desktop. In there, it should appear as "Class Library (.NET Framework)"

Answer (score 4):

I faced this issue, while creating an MVC application on my latest installation of VS2017.

**Failed:**
Tried **installing Entity Framework** using Nuget package manager[Install-Package EntityFramework], but **failed to show** Ado.NET Entity data model

**Success:**
1. open programs under control panel and select Visual Studio 2017
2. select **Change** the installation
3. [Select Modify installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfsin.png)
4. Select Individual components
5. If **SQL server data tools** already installed, deselect/uninstall this component and reinstall the same again.
6. [uninstall and reinstall SQL Server Data tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imRKU.jpg)

Note: with one component change, other components may also be deleted. You have to recheck while reinstalling