# Where are Entity Framework Tools in EF6 and Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and Entity Framework 6, and for the life of me, I cannot find the EDMX file, Entity Data Tools, Model Browser, or Entity Designer...

Am I losing my mind here? I've created multiple new projects trying to find these UI-based tools for working with the Entity Framework data models and can't seem to get anywhere.

Please help!

I believe I have the correct tools installed in the VS2017 Install:

[image: Image of VS2017 Install Option]

Comment: I don't know about VS 2017, but in 2013 you need to install SQL Server Data Tools. For SQL development, ensure that you have SQL Server Data Tools installed in Visual Studio. Click the View menu. If you don't see SQL Server Object Explorer, go to Control Panel and change Visual Studio. In the installer, select Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools.

Comment: @Sparrow -- i definitely have the SQL Server Object Explorer... just nothing related to the Entity Framework data models

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do here.  Are you trying to ADD an EF model to your project?  Or are you trying to open a previously created EF model from a project you converted to VS 2017?  If the former, you right click on the project and choose Add Item, then go to the Data Category, and choose ADO.NET Entity Data Model.  This will create an .EDMX file.  If the latter, then you just double click on the .EDMX file in your project.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch -- I already have the model setup. I'm currently manually using `Add-Migration` and `Update-Database` to scaffold my Code First back the DB. I really just want to have the UI tools to tweak a few things instead of having to use command line all the time. There is NO EDMX file anywhere. Not in the project, not on the file system, nowhere. So that's the rub. Everybody says "just double click on the EDMX file" but it does not exist. So then I hear "Add the EF model to the project" but I already have the model. So I don't know how I got a model without EDMX, but that's where I am.

Comment: @gotmike - that make no sense.  The EDMX file is the model.  That's what the M stands for.  Entity Data Model.  If you don't have an EDMX, you don't have a model, so saying you have it, but having no EDMX file doesn't make sense.  Unless of course you're talking about Code First, in which case there is no EDMX file, and you can't use the visual tools (they only work with EDMX's).

Comment: Well there u go... yes this is a code first project.

Comment: I think everyone was assuming that since you were looking for an EDMX, you were using one, and not doing code first.  In code first, the code is the model.  In traditional, the EDMX is the model and all code is generated.  Sadly, there are no visual tools for Code First.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For anyone looking at this, in my case the answer was that I was using a Code-First implementation of the Entity Framework, which apparently does NOT give you access to the Visual Tools.

So there is no EDMX file in Code-First Entity Framework.

Comment: If you don't want to separate the database access from the web application, you can add your EDMX file to the web project. To place the data access in a separate project, add a "Class Library (.NET Framework)" project to the solution, and you will find the ADO.NET Entity Data Model option in the Data section of the Add, New Item context menu option of the project. The "Class Libray (.NET Standard)" does not have that option.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar issue. I reinstalled *Entity Framework 6 tools* without luck, even reinstalled *SQL tools* (sorry, forgot exact name). But solution was very simple:

> right-click the edmx file-> choose Open with->choose ADO.NET Entity
>   Data Model Designer

Comment: tt files generating *ErrorGeneratingOutput*

Answer (score 2):

At the installation of VS2017 you had to go to Individual Components to install those tools, don't think they are installed by default.

- Individual Components

  - SDK, Libraries and Components

You can run this install from the VS Installer

[Entity Framework not appearing in Add New Item list in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42877898/entity-framework-not-appearing-in-add-new-item-list-in-visual-studio-2017)

Comment: I looked in here and found **Entity Framework 6 tools** already selected... but still can't find them in VS2017... is there an obvious place and I'm not finding them?

Comment: what type of project were you in?

Comment: to be honest, i don't remember how i set it up... it's `.NET Framework 4.6` and `Console Application` though with `EntityFramework 6.1.3` installed via NuGet

Comment: https://1drv.ms/i/s!Av7IfcJRK0fJxcl3XVVqoxc-x854-A    this is a new console full framework 4.6.1 selecting the Data tree item shows all the tools.

Comment: ok, but i've got all the models already setup, the migrations, etc. so if i add a new ADO Data Model, will that undo all the manual stuff i've done?

Comment: I even opened up a really old vs2010 project and it showed up like normal.. net 4.0 project, it shows the EMDX editor without issue. https://1drv.ms/i/s!Av7IfcJRK0fJxcl4fAlqT1b-yp7jkA

Comment: from trying to hunt this down all over the web for a while now, it seems like that's the case for most people. hence the big problem b/c everybody just says *click on the EDMX file* but i can't find any indication anywhere about how to get the EDMX file if it's not there. highly frustrating for sure.

Comment: i also went back and opened in vs2015 and same thing... no EDMX and no tools to be found...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143999/discussion-between-mvermef-and-gotmike).

Answer (score 1):

Please also see the current [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/install). They state that for current Visual Studio versions, the tools will be included. For previous versions, separate installers (MSI packages, not extensions) are available for download at the Microsoft Download Center. F.e., see [Visual Studio Releases > Visual Studio 2013](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/what-is-new/visual-studio#visual-studio-2013), which will tell you where to find the MSI for Visual Studio 2013.

As in response to gotmike's accepted answer, today there's an 3rd party marketplace extension called [Entity Framework Visual Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=michaelsawczyn.EFDesigner), which [can be used](https://msawczyn.github.io/EFDesigner/Importing.html) (I didn't try it myself) to generate a visual representation out of the code first model/POCO classes.

Also note that the Entity Framework Power Tools always had the feature to preview code first entities in a designer view called "View Entity Data Model (Read-only)". This option appears in your context menu when you select a model class derived from DbContext.