# Entity Framework missing in VS 2017 and 2019

Tags: visual-studio-code, entity-framework-6

I couldn't add Entity Framework to my project. I don't see it under data for some reason not sure what is wrong. 
I tried installing EntityFramework through nuget.. Also confirmed its available in individual components under SDKs,libraries

Appreciated your time and suggestion. Thanks a lot

[Adding new item into Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mMPQ.png)

[Components Installed in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8Ri8.png)

Comment: Have you added it via Nuget? https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/

Comment: This is a duplicate for example of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43920397/where-are-entity-framework-tools-in-ef6-and-visual-studio-2017. Also can you change the tag because clearly you are not referring to Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Thanks Steve and Eric..  Yes i added thru Nuget still same issue.. I also see entity framework 6 is  checked under individual component.. not sure what is missing..